# multiple option texts are identified by Cypress

Tags: cypress

When i am passing on the below command .get('.mat-option-text') Cy is identifying even the options of the dropdowns which are not in focus. Due to this Cy is trying to click the options which are not even visible and tests are failing. Any help on this? I want to click the option which is currently in focus.

```
cy.contains('Test Options')
.click({force: true})
.get('.mat-option-text').and('be.visible')
.contains('NOT SURE')
.click({force: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are confusing the word [focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) with the element being viewable in the viewport.

If you want to select the focused option you can do it vía `cy.focused()`, [more info](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/focused.html#Syntax)

But I think that you are referring to being able to click on something that is not viewable in the dropdown. Here you can use `scrollTo` to [navigate to some position](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto.html#Coordinates) of the dropdown if you know the position or the coordinates:

```
cy.contains('Test Options')
.click()
.scrollTo('bottom')
```

Or you can scroll into view given the element like this:

```
cy.contains('Test Options')
.click()
.get('.mat-option-text')
.contains('NOT SURE')
.scrollIntoView()
.click();
```

Hope that this helps

Comment: Here I have not mentioned that the .mat-option-text finding all the option texts of more than 5 drop-downs. The option texts are same in all those drop-downs. Let's say I am on 2nd drop-down and want to select option NO. The 1st drop down is also having option NO. Here Cypress trying to select option from the 1st drop-down. Due to this it's failing.

Comment: @Sam to target the 2nd dropdown try `cy.contains('Test Options').eq(1).click()...`.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I have tried thats earlier and its working. But looking for a more cleaner code.

Comment: That code is pretty clean. Please explain what you do not like about it.